# Images are sending and receiving in delay while sending by PHP socket

Tags: php, iphone, sockets

I'm working on a video chat app by using PHP socket and iPhone.

I'm using below tutorial to send images by socket
http://www.binarytides.com/php-socket-programming-tutorial/

I'm sending Images through socket.

I have change the below code to send images multiple clients

```
// Handle Input
            for($i = 0; $i < $this->max_clients; $i++) // for each client
            {
                if(isset($this->clients[$i]))
                {
                    if(in_array($this->clients[$i]->socket, $read))
                    {
                        $input = socket_read($this->clients[$i]->socket, $this->max_read);
                        if($input == null)
                        {
                            $this->disconnect($i);
                        }
                        else
                        {  
                            for($mx=0; $mx < count($this->clients); $mx++ ){
                                if($mx != $i ){
                                    $this->trigger_hooks("INPUT",$this->clients[$mx],$input);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

When we send the images in loop  (through Iphone client)
its taking time in sending  and receiving (1 or 2 second delay)
and after 5-10 minute it fail to send the images

How can I send images fast for video ?

Please Reply ...

Comment: A video file isn't simply a bunch of jpg's put in a sequence. It's a bunch of complex encoding to make sure that the data fills a lot less than 30 pictures a second would. Essentially you only want to send the updating pixels/areas to make sure that it's sending even quicker. Creating some sort of threshold how much a pixel has to change in colour before sending, might also be worthwhile looking into.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , can you please tell me any tutorial link to send images  actually we are trying to send images in loop for video chat